# WinHttp Post fail to retrieve website content

Tags: post, web, winhttp

This issue happen when calling to https, but works fine when call to http.

How can I resolve this?

Full working code at below:

```
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next

Dim strURL, objWinHttp, strResponse


Set objWinHttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
objWinHttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"


'Calling to https fail to retrieve content

strURL= "https://210.5.42.59:8443/sitepreview/http/test2.com/readme.txt"
WScript.Echo strURL

strResponse= CallHTTPTest(strURL)
WScript.Echo strResponse


'Calling to http successfully retrieve content

strURL= "http://ezinearticles.com/?How-To-Clean-a-Car-With-Car-Signs&id=6452594"
WScript.Echo strURL

strResponse= CallHTTPTest(strURL)
WScript.Echo strResponse



Function CallHTTPTest(strURL)

    objWinHttp.Open "POST", strURL, false
    objWinHttp.Send 

    objWinHttp.SetTimeouts 5000, 60000, 30000, 420000
    objWinHttp.WaitforResponse(440000)

    CallHTTPTest= objWinHttp.ResponseText

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to negotiate the SSL certificates:

[Using SSL with WinHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384076%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)